# How to type defaultProps in React Higher-Order Component

Tags: reactjs, typescript

My Higher-Order Component does not recognize the defaultProps which are fulfilled in the passed component.  How can I type this properly?

Here's a basic example:

```
import React from 'react';

// HOC
const withTheme = <P extends {}>(Comp: React.ComponentType<P>) => {
    return Comp as React.ComponentType<P> & {
        defaultProps: typeof Comp['defaultProps'];
    };
}

class Button extends React.Component<{size: string }> {
    static defaultProps = {
        size: 'l'
    }
}

const ThemedButton = withTheme(Button)

// here's the problem:
// left-hand side is Partial or undefined
// right-hand side is defined, but `withTheme` can't infer it
ThemedButton.defaultProps = Button.defaultProps;

// Button works fine
const a = () => <Button />
// ThemedButton does not work fine
const b = () => <ThemedButton />
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wG4AoctCAOwGd4B3YGACwBVWkQk4BeOAB4ACnCQAPGEhoATOnADeAXwB8ACgDCuMAC5ExGADot4WtJjsAnmCQiVASn4rF5OG7hEYAVyg04JsDgUeWR0IwCzGgtrW2FnADIXd2S4GSRMFC8AGxhhHDA6PRgYiEx-bQBtfDSM7Nz8unwAXQpkpQolSjQs4PkAIS8YGFoxSWk5fTDjbUiYQQU6YAAvJD0GKGAaAHM4VST3BhQYYDRU9MycvIgC-n2UuEWVvXws-Fd3Ts6qWgY4Tm4kDIBkMRgJmGx-jw1MDhjR7ORIYCYbRDDULvVrvIBMiaKjznUrgUKN96PAULc1I4+M5BDi4AB6FQk34AIwpVJpiKBg1hDJUQA)

Is there a recommended way to work with these props and type it properly?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this meets your requirement. It seems a bit complex, because the `defaultProps` type is really hard to be got from `Button`. Finally I tried many things, and the result is following:

```
const withTheme = <
  C extends React.ComponentType<any>, // Component type
  T, // Default theme props type
  Props = C extends React.ComponentType<infer R> ? R : never // Props type
>(
  Comp: C,
  defaultProps?: T extends Partial<Props> ? T : never
) => {
  return (
    props: Omit<Props, keyof (typeof Comp['defaultProps'] & T)> &
      Partial<typeof Comp['defaultProps'] & T> &
      JSX.LibraryManagedAttributes<C, { children?: ReactNode }>
  ) => <Comp {...defaultProps} {...props} />;
};

class Button extends React.Component<{
  size: string;
  id: number;
  theme: string;
}> {
  static defaultProps = {
    size: 'small',
  };
}

const a0 = () => <Button id={1} />; // Error
const b0 = () => <Button id={1} theme="dark" />; // OK

const ThemeButton1 = withTheme(Button);

const a1 = () => <ThemeButton1 id={1} />; // Error
const b1 = () => <ThemeButton1 id={1} theme="dark" />; // OK

const ThemeButton2 = withTheme(Button, {
  theme: 'dark',
});

const a2 = () => <ThemeButton2 />; // Error
const b2 = () => <ThemeButton2 id={1} />; // OK
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDejUYByEAJknAL5wBmUEIcA5FATIwNwBQnaEAdgGd4Ad2AwAFgBVxSEOQC8cADyc4cAMJwkADxhI+JAfnQwAdOvqQ++mJICeYJEpR87APmwB6Txsv8bcDAOSKpwkl4+ACJI1CgArgA28BKy5GB0YEZBjqEAChlGipo6egZGyCbmftZ8tsFKwHzUSFCIbnAA-IhwAFxw1gBuLXDecPkQmYHBnG4AFKEW4H3qmKFksYkw45kdfZJauvqGYyiwwCgJStsC7V37fYMtnACUcPLtOKEsMHFQfHDzNRqdITAR9ADyIDEVwK2AA1kg7BBqADskhkb5wABtRjreJJa6MAC6cAAZGFnu1SaEgSczhclGiMYswDi8ZtCSTyZIqTSgQApADKAA1TAAZYAAIygpzsAFkXCgAOZIEgAQRgMCgUriegEShWuDgaHEwASJBYfF2xiIpHIFDcoVe72ULNwpg97IJBSoOA9phBmSonjcXAoXB4CRQAiMACFdTB+AdSscKhgquB-LUlJ81AJgAAvJB9ITavhKrhqYAkB5xECSlqVwIyOQlrWNCucB24UJCFAwYBoOBerYFN492n5ot9RgCEAXBKMVZqcNd7i8QTwFAABnHs2d7SU8c1Ser8hwAEZg6GRj4AKJQOhQHj8IRwSW7xT7t6H4+J-5npeVApHI8gAEQkKccJgSMN6jOCADS66vvA0ipH+-AXuOogSGhcizBhfDPBGG5vigWFfgeyh4UghFYYBV6wewt5wA+T4vpu74UQCVFKDRdFwAxwEtkg4GQVA0FMSxiHIZx-EJvwABM2FiFIIkEQpfDYLmzapDO4lwkuXbEbJZHKZRP7USJhHKSGzGjGx0AcW+krmTxll8dZmnKUJUnwUhQA)

---

#### Before update

Maybe you can try it, there are other better options which let it not use `as`

```
// change
typeof Comp['defaultProps']
// into
Partial<P>
```

Comment: `defaultProps` are not equivalent to `P`; it's loosely equivalent to `Partial<P>`, but `Button` has `defaultProps` defined in this case as `{ size: string }`, which is NOT `{ size?: string }`

Comment: Well, what about changing `typeof Comp['defaultProps']` into `Partial<P>`, it works

Comment: That is not correct.  Try adding another required prop to ButtonProps (say `id: string`), WITHOUT adding that prop to `defaultProps`. `Partial<P>` makes `ThemedButton` not require ANY props!

Comment: So why not just use `const withTheme = <P,>(Comp: P) => Comp;`

Comment: That DOES work with this basic example, but the problem would then arise when `withTheme` actually does something (i.e. the HOC should actually define a default `theme` from a context provider).

Comment: I have updated my answer just now, you can try that now

Comment: Tried your updated answer.  Looks a lot better, but I actually still get errors with that.  I can't paste the link, but could you try it in https://www.typescriptlang.org/play

Comment: I have added playground link at the answer, of course I changed a little bit, now you can check it out